# How to install JScience library in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jscience

Or just any library, in general? I downloaded the bin.zip file, but I can't seem to do much with it? This is driving me up the wall...

EDIT: In other words, there is no "standard" way to do it? I know how to add the Jar files, is it ok to just put them (and the docs) anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't be much harder than putting the JARs into your project build path.

Unzip the archive and put the JARs where Eclipse can find them.